# iTextSharp table overflow wrapping

Tags: c#, itext

I am generating a two column table. When the text is too long, instead of it wrapping to the next COLUMN, it continues to the next page. Why isnt it wrapping to the next column on the same page when the text overflows?

here is what Im talking about:

[image: Screenshot]

```
string[] stringList = new string[] {"long string 1", "long string 2"};

Document doc = new Document(PageSize.LETTER);
Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
table.WidthPercentage = 100;
table.SplitLate = false;
foreach (var item in stringList) {
    paragraph.Add(item);
}

PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(paragraph);
cell.Colspan = 1;
table.AddCell(cell);
paragraph = new Paragraph();
doc.Add(table);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An iTextSharp table behaves the same way that an HTML or Excel table behaves. A cell in "column a" will always stay in that column, it will never overflow into another column. Imagine a 3 row 2 column table like below and imagine if one cell could overflow into another column:

```
| Name   | Salary  |
-------------------
| Alice  | 5,000   |
| Bob    | 50,000, |
| 000    | Charlie |
| 10,000
```

Instead, HTML, Excel, iTextSharp and most tabular software will do something like this:

```
| Name   | Salary  |
-------------------
| Alice  | 5,000   |
| Bob    | 50,000, |
|        | 000     |
| Charlie| 10,000  |
```

This method preserves the intention of the tabular data. Programs such as Adobe InDesign do allow you to specify overflows manually but I've never seen this feature in iTextSharp and I would be very surprised if it did exist.